# Render Partial View in parent view containing list of other model

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view: `UnderAge.cshtml` I'm getting a list of `Artist`(a model class) in that partial view. I have an `Index` parent view, which displays a list of `Person`(other model class), where I want to add the content from the Partial View `UnderAge.cshtml`. I've checked that the partial view works good and it has a list of two elements, the problem is when I try to show the list of `Artist` from partial view `UnderAge.cshtml` on `Index` parent view, maybe because Index is using elements from other model class (Person).

Partial View(I'm putting just the `@model` part), it display a list of Artist model class:

```
@model IEnumerable<AlexMusicStore.Models.Artist>
```

Parent view(has a different `@model`) And I'm getting this exception:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[AlexMusicStore.Models.Person]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[AlexMusicStore.Models.Artist]'.

```
@model IEnumerable<AlexMusicStore.Models.Person>

<div>
@{ 
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Artists/UnderAge.cshtml", Model);
}
    </div>
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Your passing `Model` (which is a collection of `Person` to a view which expects a collection of `Artist`

Comment: Change to this line `Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Artists/UnderAge.cshtml", Model.Artist);` So assuming your Model has a property called `Artist` and it is of type `IEnumerable<AlexMusicStore.Models.Artist>`

Comment: @Reddy, The model is `IEnumerable<Person>` - it cant possibly have a property which is `Artist` :)

Comment: @Reddy, The model doesn't recognize Artist, because is IEnumerable<Person>, and it doesn't contain a definition for Artist

Comment: @StephenMuecke ha I missed that..

Comment: @AlexGH you need to create a viewmodel which will hold ` IEnumerable<Person>` and `IEnumerable<Artist>` and pass this viewmodel to your index method and then you can do as my above comment..

Comment: @StephenMuecke I realize what's happening.. my question is what should I do so the view will display the information from the partial view even if it's not expecting an IEnumerable<Artist> type :)

Comment: But the partial is defined as `@model `IEnumerable<Artist>` so therefore it must be passed a model which is `IEnumerable<Artist>`

Comment: @Reddy that's a very good solution, I've done that already using ViewModel, but I'm wondering if is possible to show a list of elements from a different model from a Partial View into a Parent View :)

Comment: @AlexGH then you may choose to use `Html.RenderAction`

Comment: @Reddy I'll try with RenderAction and I'll let you know, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Reddy It worked good with RenderAction.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@model IEnumerable<AlexMusicStore.Models.Artist>

<div>

    @Html.Partial("UnderAge"));

</div>
```

OR

Also you can create model like this,

```
 public class Person
    {      
          public IEnumerable<ArtistModel> Artists{ get;  set;} //Passed to Partial
    }

    public class ArtistModel
    {      
           //your values here
    }
```

then display like this in Parent View

```
@model IEnumerable<AlexMusicStore.Models.Person>

<div>
@{ 
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Artists/UnderAge.cshtml", Model.Artists);
}
</div>
```